# The type HashMap is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String,

Tags: java

I am getting following error

Kindly resolve this issue.

```
Map approvers1 = new HashMap<String, AdaptApproverObject>();
List<String> approverObjectTids = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Provide the error/StackTrace is question description and not title.

Comment: The type HashMap is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, 
 AdaptApproverObject>

Comment: I suspect you've got your own `HashMap` class somewhere... although I'd recommend not using raw types, either...

Comment: import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

Comment: Which version of Java are you using ?

Comment: can you please post your complete code with imports

Comment: What is AdaptApproverObject ?

Comment: @SujithPS This has nothing to do with his error.

Comment: Is it class or inteface/abstract class ?

Comment: public final class AdaptRequestCommonGUIProcessor extends
  ApplicationCommonProcessor {

 private AdaptRequestObject adaptRequestObject = null;
 // amar SeRV00309119
 private AdaptRequestObject adaptRequest = null;

Comment: If you are using Java7 , you can omit parameters and can use this code :

Map<String, AdaptApproverObject> approvers1 = new HashMap<>();

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Check you are actually using `java.util.HashMap` and `java.util.Map` in your imports.

Comment: @AniketThakur It can. If he's importing other `HashMap`. Actually I'm almost sure that's the problem.

Comment: Other as in.. Which library has class with same name?

Comment: @AniketThakur For example, my Eclipse suggests: `com.starbase.util.collections.Map`. Which is not `java.util.Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Map<String, AdaptApproverObject> approvers1 = new HashMap<String, AdaptApproverObject>();
```

If you are using Java7 , you can omit parameters and can use this code :

```
Map<String, AdaptApproverObject> approvers1 = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: That's not the problem. You can write `Map` without specifying the type. This won't cause an error.

Comment: By omitting the generics on the 'Map', it just gives a warning and not an error.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I had defined a mapper class with the same name Map. That was why I was having this problem. Hope it gets solved for you too.

Comment: If you have a tip, but you're not sure if it will be of any help to the user because it is case specific, better post it as a comment.